# DHT11 or GPIO Library to Use in C

Tags: sensor, c, dht22, education, teaching

I am teaching a child C programming with the RPi using a project with the DHT 11. I'm coming from Python and Node on the RPi but haven't done I/O on the RPi in C. What are some available libraries we could use, where would I find them, and what are their benefits?

Comment: You had two not-very-related questions here so I have remove the second one.  WRT reading from `/dev` nodes, it depends on the node but it is not really pi specific and questions about this would be better off on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  However, a major purpose in using a file node based interface is to make it language agnostic, i.e., you are literally just reading and writing from them *as if* they were normal files (although they may be a bit less flexible in some ways).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the GPIO libraries available on the Pi see

http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples

For C the usual choices are

- [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/)
- [bcm2835](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/)
- [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) ([github](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio))

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd go with the bcm2835 library as its closest to the hardware.
If you want to work with a DHT11 then see: [A Custom Protocol - The DHT11/22](http://www.iot-programmer.com/index.php/books/22-raspberry-pi-and-the-iot-in-c/chapters-raspberry-pi-and-the-iot-in-c/41-raspberry-pi-and-the-iot-in-c-a-custom-protocol-the-dht11-dht22)

Which covers the entire how to use the DHT22 in more detail than you could ever need :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use WiringPi - http://wiringpi.com/ - it has a simplified API, but that's entirely optional... you can do everything you can do in C/C++.

The documentation and examples are excellent.